# Add Remote Repo From Shared Hosting (Hostgator) To SourceTree

Tags: git, ssh, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

1) I setup a local git repo on my Windows Dev machine.

2) Created a remote repo on my cloud hosting account with hostgator

3) Generated SSH keys on local machine.

4) Added Keys to hostgator

5) I can ssh to my server on port 2222 w/out a pass. And so now my local & remote repos are successfully linked.

The problem happened when I tried to add the remote repo (on hostgator) to SourceTree.

Sourcetree doesn't load SSH keys unless they are in the ppk format(my keys are not)
So I generated new key pairs using Putty and added them to hostgator and to the sourcetree SSH Agent.

Now I am not sure if I am inputting the correct address of the remote repo into SourceTree

What I tried:

```
ssh://<username>@mywebsite.com:2222/path/to/my/remote/repo.git

and

<username>@mywebsite.com:2222/path/to/my/remote/repo.git
```

I am uncertain if the problem is caused by a wrong address or the new ssh keys.

When I try to fetch from the remote repo on SourceTree I get:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false fetch <name of repo>
FATAL ERROR: Server unexpectedly closed network connection
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.



Completed with errors, see above.
```

My questions are:

1) Is my step of generating the new ppk keys and linking them WRONG?

2) What is the url/path that I should use with SourceTree?

I'm stuck :(

Comment: Does your SourceTree support PPK keys?

Comment: Yes, it only support keys generated with putty or converted with putty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of research I finally found the solution.

As I mentioned in my question Sourcetree uses Putty as it's SSH agent which wasn't working in my case.

What I needed to do was tell SourceTree to use OpenSSH instead.

In order to do so, got to:

TOOLS > OPTIONS

Under the General Tab under "SSH Client Configuration" choose OpenSSH instead of Putty/Plink.

And make sure you have pointed to the SSH key you're using to authenticate git with your server; in my case ~/.ssh/id_rsa

That's all.

Comment: You can mark your own answer and it will also benefit others who have similar questions.